# Access nested class list from outer class

Tags: java

I have a class that has a static nested class with two lists. And one of the functions within the outer class has the return type of this nested class. And this class takes in two lists in the constructor.

```
public class A {

  public static class Data {

  List<? extends Model> createdObjects;
  List<? extends Model> removedObjects;

  public Data(List<? extends Model> createdObjects , List<? extends Model> removedObjects) { 
        this.createdObjects = createdObjects;
        this.removedObjects  = removedObjects; 
  }
    public List<? extends Model> getCreatedObjects() {
        return this.createdObjects;
    }
    public List<? extends Model> getRemovedObjects() {
        return this.removedObjects;
    }
  }
public Data getData() {
List<Model> modelList = createObject();
modelList.add(model);
// Question - How should I be returning the data in the createdObjects? 
//Is this the correct way to create the data object and return it?
A.Data data = new A.Data(modelList, Collection.EMPTY_LIST);
return data;
}
}

}
```

So from I what know, createdObjects (list) can take a list of Model objects or List of an
object that extends Model. So in my case, the createObject() creates
a list, let's say List class, that extends from Model1 which in
turn extends from Model. So I suppose I can create a list of MyModel,
and then call the Data constructor along with two other empty lists (for
the sake of discussion). Could anyone confirm if this would be a correct way of doing it?

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you want to achieve here. Your `Data` constructor is not doing anything right now. By the way, this has little to do with nested classes.

Comment: Sorry but I am not sure what you want to do nor what problem you are facing. Could you clarify your question more?

Comment: I am looking for the correct way to pass the created lists back as a data object type. I guess the way I have written in the code is fine but would like to know if that's the correct way

Comment: What is `A.getData()` supposed to be doing?  How is the intented use of the produced `Data` object?  It appears that class `A` has a member `model` of type `Model` - true?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question properly, this is what I am suggesting, all code inside of your `Class A`:

```
public static Data getData(){
   // 2 list parameters for passing inside `Data` constructor.
    List<String> l1=new ArrayList<String>(); //taken String type for demonstration purpose.
    List<String> l2=new ArrayList<String>(); //taken String type for demonstration purpose.
    l1.add("A");
    A.Data test=new A.Data(l1, l2);
    return test;
   }

public static void main(String[] args){
  //for demonstration purpose accessing member variable directly instead of 
  //getter & setter.
 System.out.println(getData().createdObjects); 
}
```

Output:

```
[A]
```

As per comments, if you want to access `createdObjects` member variable of `Data` you can do it like below:

```
class A{
  .. //other code 
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(getData().getCreatedObjects());
        //OR 
        System.out.println(getData().createdObjects);
    }
}
```

Comment: @continuousLearner : you mean to say how should data be returned to `createdObjects` member variable? Moreover, your updated code's `Data` constructor is showing 3 argument, but it should be having 2 arguments.  Also you need to create a method in which you can call `modelList.add(model);`. Can you  have a look again

Comment: I am sorry, I have updated the question. Can you check now. I am looking for the correct way to pass the created lists back as a data object type. I guess the way I have written in the code is fine but would like to know if that's the correct way

Comment: `Question - How should I be returning the data in the createdObjects?`. Your `createdObjects` is one of property of `Data`. In your method `getData` you are returning `Data` -- which itself has `createdObjects` & `removedObjects`. Also, if you check my original code, you will get idea how I have returned `Data` object back to Class `A`.  I think my original answer still valid unless I misunderstood your requirement.

Comment: Noted. Thanks, I have a follow-up question. How can I access createdObjects declared in the Data class from getData() function in the outer class (A)?

Comment: @continuousLearner , updated my answer. Accessing `createdObjects` from class `A` can be done in two ways, Create `main` method & directly call `getData().getCreatedObjects()` or call `getData().createdObjects`

Answer (score 0):

You asked

> Question - How can I access the data class and assign the created objects to the create list of nested class?

The answer of this is "depends"

You excluded access modifiers on the class `A` and the `Data` constructor. That means that they are only visible from the same package. Assuming this is true, they can only be accessed by a class that resides in the same package.

```
public class Test {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // can be accessed this way
        Data myData = new Data(new ArrayList<Model>(), new ArrayList<Model>());
        // or this other way
        Data myOtherData = A.getData();
    }
}
```

So, if you want these classes to be accessible outside the package they reside in, you MUST make them public.

```
public class A {
    public static class Data {

        List<? extends Model> create;
        List<? extends Model> remove;

        public Data(List<? extends Model> create, List<? extends Model> remove) {
            this.create = create;
            this.remove = remove;
        }

    }

    // Since Data is a static field, this method is not needed.
    public static Data getData() {
        // TODO method body and return statement here
    }
}
```

Also, I suggest you control modification of `Data` through the `A` class. For example, the list objects should be pass by `A` to `Data` and not through the `Data` constructor. IF YOU MUST pass the lists through the `Data` constructor for some reason, then maybe you do need the `getData()` function.

Comment: I have updated the question. Please share your thoughts